# What causes iOS Safari to constantly reload a foreground page?

Tags: mobile-safari, reload, onbeforeunload

I keep getting reports from users on Safari that my webpage is automatically reloading itself about once per minute, *while they're using the page*.

My page doesn't do any history state modification, it doesn't use `location.reload()`, and it doesn't use a crazy amount of memory.

I know Safari might unload background tabs when it runs low on memory. What else can I do to troubleshoot why a browser reloads my page?

Is there anything in the `beforeunload` event that could help me identify the "source" of these reloads? Or is there some sort of response from an asynchronous `fetch()` call that would trigger a browser to reload a web page?